# Hydrogen Transitions in Foot

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hydrogen

I was reading through Foot's Atomic Physics, and saw this depiction of the transitions of the hydrogen atom. My understanding is that here we must require $\ell - \ell' = \pm 1$. Indeed, this is what Foot writes.

Why, then, are there no transitions shown between many states satisfying this (eg: $n=4, \ell=2$ to $n=3, \ell=1$).

Is there some other transition-constraining mechanism that I'm forgetting about?

[image: Hydrogen transitions (Foot -- Atomic Physics, pg 34)]

Comment: I think he omitted them for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we plot the hydrogen lines @ [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/lines1.pl?spectra=H%20I&limits_type=0&low_w=20&upp_w=9000&unit=1&de=0&lte_out=2&java_out=Make%20Grotrian%20Diagram&format=0&line_out=0&en_unit=0&output=0&bibrefs=1&page_size=15&show_obs_wl=1&show_calc_wl=1&unc_out=1&order_out=0&max_low_enrg=&show_av=2&max_upp_enrg=&tsb_value=0&min_str=&A_out=0&intens_out=on&max_str=&allowed_out=1&forbid_out=1&min_accur=&min_intens=&conf_out=on&term_out=on&enrg_out=on&J_out=on)
[image: NIST]
we clearly observe that the spectrum plotted by Foot is not complete. There are plenty of transitions between the states, but the NIST picture is not really helping to make the point that electric dipole transitions demand $\Delta \ell = 1$. There are other *selection rules* as well, which Foot discusses later in the book.

Comment: Thanks so much -- I felt like I was going insane

Comment: @Steve Welcome to Physics SE! If an answer is useful, you can upvote and accept it by clicking on the "check".